# How I can save values to hash map from api?

Tags: java, jackson

```
 try {
        String apikey = "-------";
        String url = "https://freecurrencyapi.net/api/v2/latest?apikey=" + apikey + "&base_currency=USD";
        URL urlForGetRequest = new URL(url);
        String readLine = null;
        HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForGetRequest.openConnection();
        conection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = conection.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(readLine);
            }
            in.close();
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Error in API Call");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How I can save values from api to Hashmap List? Where key will be first worth (e.g "JPY") and value will be worth of "JPY" (E.G 115).
I wanted to use Jackson lib, but I didn't find any information for how to do it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9XdK.png)

Comment: Please mention the return format of you API

Comment: return fromat api it's string

Comment: i added an answer please consider to accept it if it satisfy the requirement or feel free to comment under it .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is caching.  There are quite a few libraries to handle this, I would recommend EHCache, but I'm sure newer libraries have sprung up since last I did this kind of work.  You should be using a framework to facilitate web calls.  If you execute your calls from Spring, there are a set of annotations you can use that will do the caching for you behind the scenes.

Comment: guess he dosent want to cache anything and the requirement is just saving some values extracted from result .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having buffer reader consider using [RestTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) i,e

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String yurDestinationUrl= "http://blablalba";
ResponseEntity<String> response
  = restTemplate.getForEntity(yurDestinationUrl + "/1", String.class);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(response.getBody());
JsonNode name = root.path("name");

//then add extracted JsonNode to your desired map or list as you prefer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) from the json response that you are dealing with.

There is an IntelliJ plugin which called [RoboPOJOGenerator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8634-robopojogenerator) or by other websites which you can easily find with this search [json to pojo](https://www.google.com/search?q=json+to+pojo&oq=json+to&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0i271j69i60l3.1342j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

### [image: Under the context menu's new option on any project package.]

*Or you can create that POJO manually.*

After creating this class you should create gson from json string like below:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

// JSON string to Java object
Currencies currencies = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Currencies.class);
```

Finally you have a meaningful object instance which you can use/manipulate easily as you wish.